# Combining multiple collections in postman

Tags: postman-collection-runner

I am trying to run multiple postman collections at one run in jenkins

Below is my scenario
collection1.json with data1.csv and environment variable as environment1.json
collection1.json with data1.csv and environment variable as environment1.json

I want to run the above to collection in one go
-Please let me know how to combine 2 collections and run at once?
-Is there a way to download each collection in postman at once rather than doing 1 by 1?
-Example of using postman-collection-combine

Answer (score 0):

I know that Postman collection runner has some limitations, but I was able to achieve it using [this article](https://medium.com/@mnu/run-multiple-postman-collection-in-parallel-stress-ee20801922ed)

This is the script that lets you run multiple Postman collections in parallel:

```
const path = require('path')
const async = require('async')
const newman = require('newman')

const PARALLEL_RUN_COUNT = 2

const parametersForTestRun = {
    collection: path.join(__dirname, 'postman/postman_collection.json'), // your collection
    environment: path.join(__dirname, 'postman/localhost.postman_environment.json'), //your env
    reporters: 'cli'
};

parallelCollectionRun = function (done) {
    newman.run(parametersForTestRun, done);
};

let commands = []
for (let index = 0; index < PARALLEL_RUN_COUNT; index++) {
    commands.push(parallelCollectionRun);
}

// Runs the Postman sample collection thrice, in parallel.
async.parallel(
    commands,
    (err, results) => {
        err && console.error(err);

        results.forEach(function (result) {
            var failures = result.run.failures;
            console.info(failures.length ? JSON.stringify(failures.failures, null, 2) :
                `${result.collection.name} ran successfully.`);
        });
    });
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Dharman OK, I understand that. I have added the script from the article.